# HTTP Live Streaming Distribution Server Choice

Tags: apache, webserver, http-live-streaming

I'm setting up the Apple's HTTP Live Streaming System. I've read its document and the system works like: Input Audio/Video device --> Encoder --> Segmenter --> Distribution Server --> Client (iPad/iPhone...).

In my test, I used Apache HTTP Server as the Distribution Server, which means I've uploaded the playlist and generated ts segments into Apache HTTP Server, and then distributed them out to client. It works! My question here is, does the distribution server have to be some special server that supports http live streaming protocol distribution? Or just an ordinary http server will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ordinary HTTP server is all that is needed. If you have many (thousands) of viewers, you might want to use a CDN.

Comment: thanks for answer my question again~ May I ask what http server have you tested in your hls system?

Comment: @summerlismile I've used apache, nginx, iis, as well as several development frameworks that include http servers. The only part that is ever any trouble is to make sure that the correct mime types are being returned.